# The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.context"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

As I am upgrading my project from Symfony 2.6 to Symfony 3.4, I am encountering a number of issues while upgrading, a lot of dependencies has to be updated. But I am facing one issue is this:

> The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service
>   "security.context"

I read that `security.context` got deprecated in 2.6, it was split into the `TokenStorage` and the `AuthorizationChecker`.

Is there something I need to do, please help me with the solution?

Comment: More details on why the [security context object was split up](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements).  I did not want to divert the discussion below but you might consider updating from 2.6 to 2.8 first and getting rid of all the deprecation messages the profiler bar shows.  That will make jumping to 3.4 easier.  And while autowire is pretty cool, most of your existing 2.8 service files should work just fine under 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your login controller move

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
```

to

```
$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
```

also consider to use autowire https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html for your services.

Comment: Hi Nicola, this means I need to changes this line statement in the project. Am I right? As I am upgrading the whole project. I have also seen in services.yml to use  `security.context`. Do I need to make in those files too? @NicolaPez

Comment: Yes, you have to upgrade your project. Surely you have to upgrade also the services, but if you implement the autowire all this will be made from symfony

Comment: for example in services.yml , it looks like this app.twig_extension:
        `class: LinkAndLearn\Bundle\Twig\LinkAndLearnTwigExtension
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@service_container'
            - '@security.context'
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }`
Do I need to make update here?

Comment: yes, probably here you need of TokenStorage service

Comment: but really consider the autowire, I a great improvment of 3.4 and future version.

Comment: Now, it is giving me such error ` ' Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Learn\Bundle\EventListener\TaggableSubscriber::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage given, called in /var/www/html/upgrade/Learn/WebSite/var/cache/dev/ContainerKj0xrxe/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2576 in /var/www/html/upgrade/Learn/WebSite/src/Learn/Bundle/EventListener/TaggableSubscriber'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185251/discussion-between-captain-planet-and-nicolapez).

Comment: service_container must remain as dependency, also is not a good solution have the entire container ad dependency.

Comment: can you suggest a solution for the above?

Comment: Please, use the autowire, I linked you the documentation in the answer, will made all this for you.